# How do I keep a fixed background image size even if the page is zoomed in or out?

Tags: html, scroll, background-image, css

I have an image that I want to set as my background with dimensions 1x700.

It is a gradient sort of image so I need it to `repeat-x`.

The main problem I am having is that the image is not filling the entire page.  It is, however, remaining fixed.  Specifically when I scroll out I can see that the image is not filling the entire page.

The code I have works in firefox and chrome, but not in IE9.  I am also applying this skin to dotnetnuke if that makes any difference.

Here is my code:

```
body 
{   
    background-image: url('images/bg.jpg');
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if I understand correctly:

To fit the image to full screen, use the CSS property:

```
background-size:100% 100%;
```

However note that it will stretch the image if the size is not correct

Answer (score 1):

**WARNING**

Avoid messing up with browser zooming or other browser-related features, cause doing so may reduce the user experience, expecially for users who rely on such features of their favorite browser!

---

That said, the only way I know of an element to mantain its size regardless of browser zooming is by having a container element to occupy all the screen, and the inside element to have percentage measures, like this.

http://jsfiddle.net/yLFj8/4/

Answer (score 0):

Strip down the CSS and it should work.  This should be all you need.

```
body {
  background-image: url('images/bg.jpg');
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

See my example here

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/fSG7j/1/